# VS 2015 Windows 10 Universal App Designer does not load

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10, win-universal-app, xaml-designer

I am trying to build a Windows 10 Universal App in Visual Studio 2015 Community on a Windows 10 Professional machine (Developer mode is ON). However, the designer just will not load. There is no error message, it just stays stuck saying "Loading designer... You can continue working while the designer is loading in the background."

I have tried repairing Visual Studio as well and it has not changed anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It occurs to me sometimes ago; I read somewhere that you can try creating a new C# universal app project from the template and open its `MainPage.xaml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have to update your windows 10 pro OS with latest update th2_release Professional 10532. After it you would able to design your windows 
app also.

Comment: Thank you. This turned out to be the issue. My Windows Update was not working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First Login with your Microsoft or Outlook account then you will get update automatically.